# async operation is failing test cases in protractor jasmine framework

Tags: angular, automation, jasmine, protractor, ui-automation

I had code which was working absolutely fine without any issues. After opening the homepage, it was validating presence of elements on it but recently development team introduced new code which is doing async operation as soon as homepage opens and  protractor is unable to find the elements on the homepage after opening the homepage as it keeps waiting for that async operation to finish

Is there any way to ignore async operation and protractor runs test case execution smoothly or I saw ngzone concept but couldn't understand it.  Please help me in this case

I have started using and it made one tc passed but next tc failed
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

```
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); // introduced after async operation
    browser.get(homepage);
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(yourElement), 5000);
```

Comment: The question it too broad. In fact, you answered your own question right. Use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` to ignore async operations. What comes to your failures - you need to include your code, HTML, and error stack otherwise it's a shot in a dark

Answer (score 0):

```
it('',async() => {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); // introduced after async operation
    await browser.get(homepage);
    await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(yourElement), 5000);
});
```

Try the above one. Hope it helps you